# Ajax - send a request from a specific URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here was a need to send a request to ajax through another site, since requests are accepted only from it. I'm using the extension to be able to send the request, but since I not only send the request to another site but also send it from the other, I have to make `windows.open()` with some GET request (for example `?accept`), catch it and from this window already send ajax.

Q: Can I make it easier without using `windows.open ()`? This option is not very good, because when you open the page, it takes time to load it and another pop-up window closes the view for a short time.

Example code:

```
var geturl = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    window.open('https://first-site.com?accept');
});
// Because this is a Google extension, the query works in `window.open()`, which opens above
if(geturl == 'accept'){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://second-site.com/accept',
        data: {
            dataid: '...',
            passid: '...',
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){window.close();}
    });
}
```